# How likely is it that global nuclear war will make rebuilt civilizaton unable to ever reach current technological level closeTo civilization in 202x?

Tags: science-based, post-apocalypse, artificial-intelligence, nuclear-war

This is year 2029. There is a malevolent AI working in shadows. There is also a group of people who oppose it, who also work in shadows. At some point they understand that their struggle is close to be over, that the AI is close to reaching the point where it would be able to take over the humanity, while they would be powerless to stop it. So they turn to desperate measures. They trigger a global nuclear war, causing collapse of modern civilization and the AI with it. Lot's of people die, but the humankind survives. They hoped that the humankind will never be able to recover enough to build such technological marvel as said AI ever again.

How reasonable is such expectation? One argument for such position, is that modern civilization exhausted many easy-to-access resources that were used to build it. And in order to get hands on hardrer-to-access resources you need to build infrastructure, create machinery, tools, chemicals, etc. that you are unlikey to create without harvesting easy-to-access resources in the first place. So this is kind of "a chicken or an egg" problem here, and whole civilization can get stuck at certain level of development, like eternal Middel Ages or eternal 19th century.

Comment: *"modern civilization exhausted many easy-to-access resources that were used to build it":* No, it did not. There is no natural resource which is more expensive now than it was in the 1800s. On the contrary, many resources, such as iron, steel, copper, gold, silver, and aluminium, would be available in large quantities ready for use with minimal effort.

Comment: @user161005 Alex is right. There would be a lot of metals, etc, already processed. And some mines would survive. Coal is abundant, gas is abundant.

Comment: Modern civilization absolutely requires a large population. Reduction in population will regress civilization. So if the world lost half its population civilization would look like the 1970's. But if it lost say 80% we'd likely return to the middle ages. Much more than that and there's a chance of extinction.

Comment: as long as the human species survives it can eventually climb back to any technological level, the only question is how long. modern civilization exhausted many easily access resources but created many others. steel plants, tire yards, junk yards, giant pyramids made of sulfur, even dumps will become highly valuable resource concentrations.

Comment: You should probably watch Battlestar Galactica. All of this has happened before and will happen again...

Comment: @AlexP Oil used to bubble out of the ground in Pennsylvania and Texas. You could drill for oil with a hand shovel. Now you have to use a platform in the middle of the ocean that goes through 3 miles of water and another mile of rock. The same can be said of coal, most metal ores besides iron and aluminum, etc. It's very much true. These things, if they're cheaper at all, are only so because they use high technology for extraction.

Comment: @John O: The U.S. of A. is not the entire world, and it being a faraway and foreign country, I don't know all that well what resources are easily available there. There are plenty of places in this world where coal is free for the taking, with a shovel or (in real life) with a bulldozer; same for copper ore. And even for petroleum one does not *have to* go drilling in the ocean; it is not Mother Nature's fault that Americans do not like Persians or Russians. With easily gotten coal, iron, and copper the civilization surely can progress.

Comment: @AlexP They are cheaper only because our technological skills on how to extract them have improved.

Comment: @AlexP Everything I've said applies elsewhere. It just happened at different times. Coal elsewhere in the world does you little good, if you don't have the petroleum to ship it where it needs to be, and if it happened to be close to any of those places they'd have already done it. Same with the oil... plenty available supposing you can drill 5 miles deep. Except you can't if you're struggling along with 1860s-level drilling technology. It's easy to mine copper out of a landfill... unless you're stuck with medieval processing skills. Even in Iran, even in Russia... all the easy stuff's gone.

Comment: @JohnO It seems like your reasoning is different from other users here. I would appreciate if you posted answer to my question.

Comment: @user161005 The short answer is that once a civilization reaches about the 1920s-level of tech, that's it. They can keep going as long as they don't stumble, but when they do they never get back up. There's little reason to suppose that one can skip directly over fossil fuels and go directly to fusion on a second attempt. And it's not just fuels, rare metals... hell, it's even biomass in the short term (5000 years). It's the reason that ancient astronaut and lost civ theories are bunk.

Comment: @JohnO Why 1920-s level of tech? What will prevent them to go to, say, 1930-s level of tech?

Comment: @user161005 Petroleum drilling, they're starting to hit depths that are no longer trivial. Decades of institutional knowledge in addition to tech that makes it possible, that you only get with decades of drilling more shallowly. Same's going on with coal. Ore mining is changing, starting to use heavy machinery regularly. This is a rough estimate. Might be +/- 20 years... if you need something more precise, it'd require extensive research. Whatever the actual year is, you just don't get it unless you've had everything else previously... and you only get that if there is easy-to-get stuff left.

Answer (score 13):

The "problem" with a global Nuclear war, at least as currently imagined is that it will not destroy everything. Billions would die in the destruction and aftermath, but there would be areas that were much less affected. Especially in the Southern Hemisphere. As the air circulation between North and South is much less than between East and West places like New Zealand would probably survive even if a couple of big cities were hit. There are plenty of smaller settlements spread out as well as towns, plenty to eat.

The majority of human knowledge would not be lost and within a few decades there would be green shoots of growth again. There is enough coal to last 500 years and still plenty of oil especially for a drastically reduced population who might be keener to use other energy sources such as wind and solar anyway.

Comment: Indeed "nuclear winter" only affects the Northern Hemisphere. https://www.britannica.com/science/nuclear-winter Several hundred million tons of this smoke and soot would be shepherded by strong west-to-east winds until they would form a uniform belt of particles encircling the Northern Hemisphere from 30° to 60° latitude. These thick black clouds could block out all but a fraction of the Sun’s light for a period as long as several weeks. Surface temperatures would plunge for a few weeks as a consequence, perhaps by as much as 11° to 22° C (20° to 40° F).

Comment: Isn't the southern hemisphere being unaffected a byproduct of the nuclear war happening between USA/Europe and Russia/China, both located on the northern hemisphere? This may not be true if the anti-AI group has any control on where to send the nukes. They'll go for a roughly homogenous distribution.

Comment: That is true to some extent, but there are far fewer people in the Southern hemisphere who are fairly well spread out. And destructive as they are nuclear weapons cause a relatively small amount of utter destruction on a country the size and shape of New Zealand and the rest. Of course with more bombs who knows there must be a limit.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of problems here based around how you have framed the question. Specifically there is insufficient detail about a couple of key issues. (None of what follows is meant as a criticism of the your scenario BTW.)

Firstly there is the question of how much control the the secret group has over the shape/extent/severity of the war. Starting a nuclear conflict is one thing. Precisely controlling the number of bombs used, what strikes land where and what critical infrastructure and population centers are destroyed or survive is an order of magnitude harder. So frankly? More details would be useful.

If the 'organization' did have high enough a degree of control to more or less shape the war to their will then they probably also have the resources/influence needed to track down and defeat the AI *without* launching a war in the first place.

Secondly (and feeding into the first problem) there are no real details provided about the nature of the AI itself and its capabilities. For example if you use the Terminator series as a guide the AI in question has at times been either;

1. A centralized intelligence based in specific (well protected) location.
2. A distributed network capable of infiltrating and utilizing multiple different computer networks to extend its 'intelligence' across most parts of the planet
3. A highly highly mobile centralized 'individual' unit presumably with backups located at backup 'bodies' stored away for safe keeping.

Take your pick,

Point is that given these factors its entirely possible that humans would either re-develop a suitably advanced technological society within a couple of generations because parts of the globe were less impacted by the war than others or alternately the AI would remain safe in some secure location until they did.

Comment: They can only trigger a nuclear war. The AI is run on a supercomputer at some specific place.

Comment: I think AI should be distributed over the entire internet for this plan to have any sort of meaning. If it is at some specific place, it will be more productive to strike potential location rather than an all out nuclear war. If it is the entire computational power of the world, then a nuclear war that will destroy networking infrastructure will be the only way to get rid of the AI.

Comment: user161005. So in that case it would appear to be tie at best. Alternately the AI might win. The organization can't control specific strike locations so if the AI has hidden itself in some remote/secure locality the chances of it being taken out during the war are remote. On the other hand if it is hidden remotely the AI has the problem of 'reconnecting'  to any new internet. (And powering itself long enough to do so.)

Answer (score 3):

## Given enough time, likely

A lot of people I think are missing the question. Let's ignore the fact that the nukes might kill off most of humanity and launch us into a dark age, LITERALLY, as the dark clouds cut off sunlight, hearlding a nuclear winter.However, in a comment, the author of this question noted humanity survived, so we can assume this war didn't crack the planet in two, simply cause a massive species wide setback.

### Things look up, then down

Radiation and nuclear winter will fade, and life will find a way to survive. As long as humans exist, they will probably thrive. One key factor is this - the way our modern society formed is through a number of stages. Most of which can be infinitely repeated. Hunting gathering - agriculture - numerous scientific and philisophical discoveries - so many more, until the crucial stage that leads us to today, the industrial revolution, which can not be repeated infinitely, as the way we did it was with non renewable fuels, such as coal and gas.

This is a major problem for our would-be AI creators, AKA humanity, as that crucial resource is no longer avalibale as much as it was, in the same places.

### However

Fortunately for them (and unfortunately for the organization), not all coal and oil is destroyed, a lot of it is gone sure, but eventually, with enough time, pass thousands and millions of years, society will develop a method to extract it, especially if libraries (or more crucially a backup of the internet and a computer), exist.

With a huge setback like this, it might take millenia (though probably shorter, as farmers, and our genetically modified crops (that tend to produce huge amounts more), engineers, computer builders, etc. will still be there, and along with them, their knowledge.

### Conclusion (TL:DR)

As long as this doesnt destroy the world and wipe out humanity, it is likely. Our knowledge from thousands of years will still be there (10% of the population works in agriculture, so we wont have to start as hunter gatherers at least, and most other fields will probably have specialists remaining). Depending on the level of nuclear war, a lot of rural infrastructure (considering that the nukes probably will target population centers), will probably be there as well. Depending on how catastrophic this is, humanity would need anywhere between 5000 years (in the worst-worst case, almost all knowledge is lost), and 10 years (infrastructure remains, many specialists remain, the internet is backed up, and after a couple of years rebuilding some scientist decides to boot up some code he found, and it was the AI D: ).

Comment: It would definitely take longer the second time around, though. All of the "easy" oil and gas has already been mined out, along with all of the "easy" metals. So the second rise of humanity would have to spend a lot more resources to extract anything from the earth.

Comment: Metals will be easier to mine from old buildings.

Comment: It is not certain that humanity will go through a fossil phase again.

Answer (score 1):

Given enough time then there is nothing to physically stop civilisation rebuilding all of the modern technology.
It is unlikely to be the same as before, if there is enough knowledge and organisation amongst the survivors they can skip lots of the old stages of technology, maybe go straight to renewable energy and not need fossil fuels etc.

What your secret society needs to do is to spread information that a rogue AI was responsible for the destruction, that way you can make it almost a religious objection to developing AI in the future.

If you really wanted to you could make a whole religion about technology being bad and try to force society to stay at a medieval technology level, for an example of this in existing works check out the [safehold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safehold) series by David Webber

Comment: I'm very sceptical about long-term effectiveness of religious taboos.

Comment: @user161005 - assuming the religion maintains it's power and doesn't get supplanted taboos hold up quite well, for an example look at kosher or halal restrictions on pork products.  Of course a taboo on AI for a culture that will take 1000 years before they have computers again might be a challenge

Answer (score 0):

All out nuclear war would probably force the survivors underground if it didn't trigger a global environmental collapse and wipe everyone out. Just the ozone layer disturbance and comcommitent problems would do that.

The technology would still be documented though, so eventually the capability could exist to make another such AI. That doesn't mean it will happen though, and it would be a very long time before it's possible I would think. People will be busy.

Comment: [All out nuclear war would probably force the survivors underground if it didn't trigger a global environmental collapse and wipe everyone out] - Citation required

Answer (score 0):

Global nuclear war isn't simply a matter of radioactive areas and the destruction of cities and infrastructure.

Consider what happened only 1500 years ago:

> A mysterious fog plunged Europe, the Middle East, and parts of Asia into darkness, day and night—for 18 months.
> "For the sun gave forth its light without brightness, like the moon, during the whole year," wrote Byzantine historian Procopius.
> Temperatures in the summer of 536 fell 1.5°C to 2.5°C, initiating the coldest decade in the past 2300 years.
> Snow fell that summer in China; crops failed; people starved.
> The Irish chronicles record "a failure of bread from the years 536–539."
> — [Why 536 was ‘the worst year to be alive' | Science | AAAS](https://www.science.org/content/article/why-536-was-worst-year-be-alive)

That massive starvation was caused by a single volcano in Iceland.

66 million years earlier, a single [asteroid collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous%E2%80%93Paleogene_extinction_event) caused an [impact winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_winter) that destroyed 75% of the plant and animal species on earth.

A global nuclear war would have a similar effect.
Nowhere on Earth would be safe.

The chances of human survival would be very slim, and that of civilization effectively non-existent.

Something like *Dr. Strangelove*'s [mineshafts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybSzoLCCX-Y&t=251s) might help prolong the agony, but they would require massive preparation, and I doubt the AIs are going to provide any warning.

Comment: Survival of humanity already happened, so we can take it for granted. The question is if they will be able to create new AI someday.

Answer (score 0):

### You gotta hate energy

**The backbone of our modern society is energy**. Energy to power farming machines. Energy to power factories. Energy to power our cars and trucks. Energy to power our fridges, our lights, our phones, our HVAC, our TVs, etc.

Resources are a red herring, as @AlexP pointed in comments, resources now are cheaper than ever. You'll certainly disagree if you drive a car, but overall it's true. Because we have machines that can extract resources faster and in larger quantities than by hand. Because we have trucks, boats and planes that can transport them faster, further, and in larger quantities. Because, in a nutshell, we have the energy to make it happen.

Without abundant energy, you're back to having to work the fields manually. That means no workforce for the factories, that means no advacned technologies, and that means definitely no AI.

Again, *the backbone of our modern society is energy*.

---

So, if you want to stop society's development, you'll have to think about restricting access to energy. And I don't think the answer to that can be a strictly technical solution, I think the answer here is cultural: **make energy evil**.

You really can spin any form of energy as evil, and it's only going to be easier in the aftermath of a disaster.

Survivors of the nuclear apocalypse could easily develop a deep cultural aversion to atomic energy, when Hiroshima, Nagasaki, Chernobyl and Fukushima are already valid reasons to be wary. By a similar logic, they could swear off fossil fuels that poisons clean air, soil and water, which is in short supply already. When dams breaks and valleys are flooded, destroying entire villages, that's another reason to think twice about hydroelectricity.

In a nutshell, a core belief of your society should be that harming the environment is a horrendous crime against humanity, and it follows many forms of energy are simply evil because of that. And you already have evidence to support that line of thinking: that time humanity was almost wiped out.

---

**That can't last forever**. There's no guarantee your society won't change and won't cast away some of those superstitions about the evils of energy. There will never be any guarantee humanity won't repeat the same mistakes.

Your hope here is that humans are very good at keeping alive prejudices for no real reason. So maybe this fear of energy will remain ingrained in some form well into your society's new golden age, maybe they'll truly stop to ponder every new technology and whether they really need it, or whether it will inevitably blow up in their face, like it blew up in their ancestors' collective faces.

Comment: You write that *you can spin any form of energy as evil*.  How do you spin a solar cooker as evil?

Comment: @gerrit Are you a witch, that you can cook without wood and flint and steel?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - Fint snd steel? Wood?!? How dare you try to use fire! That is forbidden and the punishment is to be burned at the stake. This does create a moral dilemma, but that can be discussed after the execution.

Comment: @gerrit I could point out that it's a woefully unnatural process, and who do you think you are do defy Mother Nature, or tell tales of accidental fires started by a solar cooker, or tales of giant solar cookers that once helped power the hubris of man. But the larger point in here is you probably had to stop and think before coming up with solar cookers, and think about a technology that is very useful and doesn't impact the environment, as long as you keep it scaled down.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario is not very realistic because it is so much easier to defeat AI than you suggest. A "malevolent AI" would be sponsored by a rogue state as any business person would be designing an AI just to make more money. We have far more ability to hamper the technological advance of a rogue state than needing to trigger a nuclear war.

Right now, it is possible to defeat AI in facial recognition by simply painting certain patterns on the face. Many a situation on the road has already defeated the AI used by Tesla to the death of the owner who was reading while the AI drove the car.

AI requires a massive computer system and the infrastructure needed to keep such a system up and constantly replacing components. A rogue state would have trouble getting the parts. The results will be errors in the AI. AWS already has to do a fair amount of work to hide how many hardware failures they encounter and how many times data has been corrupted at rest (bit rot). This AI would be somewhat "zombie" like with all the errors.

Between the hardware failures and the problems with building such a system when being sanctioned and secretly attacked by all the intelligence services, I doubt that the AI would be successful.

Answer (score 0):

**Impossible**

Humanity, already having proven that they could create the AI, will do it again, it's just a matter of time.

Worse, you're talking about the species that's at the top of the proverbial food chain *because of its problem-solving skills.* Almost every creature on Earth can bring low a human (I'm lookin' at you, mosquitos!), but we're on top because we can figure out how to solve any problem — other than mothers-in-law. Can't figure that one out. But let's look past that one.

All the easy-to-get-to oil gone? Humanity will simply develop another energy source. All the coal is finally burned out thanks to serendipitously placed nukes? No problem, we'll figure that one out.

Suggesting that there's something that could block humanity's progress is incredibly short-sighted and a terrible under-estimation not based on available facts.

Worse, *you didn't specify a time period.* So it doesn't matter how long it takes. Are we actually forced to deal with getting the hard-to-get oil?

Fine.

That just delays the inevitable.

The only way to stop humanity from reaching the same level of technological development is to kill all the humans and let Mother Nature start over with a less capable problem-solving species. But I doubt even that would work — it would simply take more time.